# Por que esse programa não funciona no Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>          
    <fieldset><legend>Escolha</legend>
        <select>
            <optgroup label="Decimal" onclick="f_decimal()">
                <option onclick="carro()">Carro</option>
                <option onclick="moto()">Moto</option>
            </optgroup>     
        </select>   
    </fieldset> 
    <script>
        function carro(){
        alert("Você escolheu carro.")
        }
        function moto(){
        alert("Você escolheu moto.")
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: A proposta é a seguinte, deve-se escolher uma opção no select, e um alerta deve aparecer mostrando a opção escolhida. (Funciona nos navegadores: Edge e Firefox, mas não no Chrome).

Comment: @Muka149 http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com.br/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html . Utilize atributos `data-type="carro"` e o evento `onchange` para identificar o tipo de veículo.

Comment: O certo seria onchange no select, o click não serve para select

Comment: Também não funciona no Opera, e no IE11

Comment: Você esqueceu de declarar o `<title></title>` dentro do head do seu HTML. Se você omitir a tag `<title>` o documento não é validado como um arquivo HTML. Fonte:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag [`option`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) contém os eventos globais do HTML e isso inclui o `onclick()`. Por algum motivo essa relação pode ou não funcionar em alguns navegadores. Isso se deve ao fato de não se utilizar o evento `onclick()` nos elementos `option` e sim utilizar o evento [`onchange()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) na tag [`select`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).

```js
function mudou() {
  
  var valor = document.getElementById("teste").value;
  
  if(valor == "carro") {
    carro();
  }
  else if(valor == "moto") {
    moto();
  }
  
}

function carro(){
  alert("Você escolheu carro.")
}

function moto(){
  alert("Você escolheu moto.")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>          
    <fieldset><legend>Escolha</legend>
        <select id="teste" onchange="mudou()">
            <optgroup label="Decimal">
                <option value="carro">Carro</option>
                <option value="moto">Moto</option>
            </optgroup>     
        </select>   
    </fieldset> 
</html>
```

Referências:

- [onclick event is not working with option tag in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065274/onclick-event-is-not-working-with-option-tag-in-html);
- [How to use onClick() or onSelect() on option tag in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-a-jsp-page)